# Get value/state of checkbox for each row in a Django when POST

Tags: python, django, forms, sqlite, django-forms

I want to display a table with :

- on rows: the date for each weekday (calculate in my views.py)
- on columns: the Mealselection of an user.

I can get value from models and display it :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExURv.png

But when i look source code on the page i see https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLb2T.jpg

So obviously it does not work when i try to save the user choice because it will update only one date, today for exemple, since there are the same form id i think.

- I try with a formset but i can't pass initial value to the template "selection_template.html" (i try with the exemple below but don't work because i need to display the user selection in relation with date of weekday.

```py
formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=[{'title': "Form %d" % (i+1),
                                   'pub_date': datetime.date.today()} for i in range(10)])
```

- I know how to display multi form using formset but don't know how to pass value to the template.

**models.py**

```py
class MealSelection(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    salad = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    meal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sandwich = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**forms.py**

```py
class GetUserMeal(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MealSelection
        fields = ['meal', 'salad', 'sandwich']
        widget = forms.CheckboxInput(
            attrs={
                'name': 'choices'
            }
        )
```

**views.py**

```py
for day in weekDay:
        try:
            userSelection  = MealSelection.objects.get(user=u1,date=startWeek + datetime.timedelta(days=daysCount))
            userSelection = {'meal':userSelection.meal, 'salad':userSelection.salad, 'sandwich':userSelection.sandwich}
        except:
            userSelection = {'meal':False, 'salad':False, 'sandwich':False}
            userSelection = forms.GetUserMeal(userSelection)
        dateDayCorresp[day] = {'date':startWeek + datetime.timedelta(days=daysCount),'userSelection': userSelection}
        daysCount += 1
```

**selection_template.html**

```py
<form method="post">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered vertical-align">
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-primary">
        <th rowspan="2">Jour</th>
        <th colspan="3">Repas</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-success">
          <th scope="col">Repas</th>
          <th scope="col">Salade</th>
          <th scope="col">Sandwich</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% csrf_token %}
          {% for day in dateDayCorresp.items %}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="table-warning">
              {{day.0}} ({{day.1.date}})
              <!-- {{day.1.userSelection}} -->
            </th>
            {% for field in day.1.userSelection %}
            <td>
              <label>{{ field }}</label>
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      </table>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block fixed-bottom" id="buttonSave">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: This might be a case where not using a Django form is easier than using one. There isn't much validation needed on a set of binary choices. You can safely and easily render your own HTML and collect the user response from request.POST. Just make sure that your code does not crash if the expected items are missing from request.POST (which would require malign intent, I think).

Comment: Thank you, i get it working without form but takes more lines :p